# Running multiple tox testenv matching a name fragment

Tags: python, continuous-integration, tox

## Rationale

With complex dependency matrix, tox testenv name patterns end up being a list like

```
py37-pytest5-framework1
py37-pytest5-framework2
py37-pytest6-framework1
py37-pytest6-framework2
py38-pytest5-framework1
py38-pytest5-framework2
py38-pytest6-framework1
py38-pytest6-framework2
...
py310-pytest6-framework2
```

While the inner tox.ini syntax allows configuring a lot of things with name fragments, e.g.

```
[testenv]
basepython =
    py37: python3.7
    py38: python3.8
    py39: python3.9
    py310: python3.10
deps =
    pytest5: pytest ~= 5.0
    pytest6: pytest ~= 6.0
    framework1: framework ~= 1.0
    framework2: framework ~= 2.0
setenv =
    framework2: FOO=bar
```

I find there is no way in telling the tox CLI in running all testenvs matching a name fragment like `tox -e py39` or `tox -e framework2`.

### Issues

The main drawback is that most usually CI testing jobs will end up being segregated by python version, so you end up writing instructions like

```
tox -e $PY-pytest5-framework1,$PY-pytest5-framework2,$PY-pytest6-framework1,$PY-pytest6-framework2
```

but then the CI jobs definition is coupled to the tox test matrix because it must be aware of:

- testenvs being added or removed
- matrix exclusions like pytest-5 is not compatible with python-3.10

And this is cumbersome to maintain.

### Incomplete workaround

An easy-to-go workaround is simply running `tox --skip-missing-interpreters`, but the drawbacks are:

- CI jobs can't be segregated by framework version instead of python version, for example to reuse some special framework cache
- CI VMs could feature system python installations beyond the one targeted by each job, so you could en up with e.g. python-3.8 being run in all CI jobs.

## Question

Am I missing some out-of-the-box mechanism to filter the testenvs to be run with a fragment that powers me to write CI jobs agnostic to the tox dependency matrix? I mean something like `tox -e '*-framework2'`.

Am I bound to filter and aggregate the output of `tox --listenvs` with shell tricks?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could negate a regex pattern for the `TOX_SKIP_ENV` as the following:

```
$ env TOX_SKIP_ENV='.*[^-framework2]$' tox
```

`tox4`, which will be introduced within the next couple of months, introduces [labels](https://tox.wiki/en/rewrite/config.html#labels). While this may be not an immediate help for your problem, maybe you see a way to simplify your `tox.ini`.

Comment: TOX_SKIP_ENV seems the way to go, but negative regex are hard so I'll definetely watch for the tox v4 release.

Comment: Finally got it working with `TOX_SKIP_ENV='^((?!testenv-fragment).)*$'` if you'd like to generalise the answer for a name fragment in any position